# IndexOutOfRangeException (string[])

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, исключения

Объявлен массив:

```
public static string[] topUsers = new string[65536];
```

И данный код работает с ним:

```
public async void GetGlobalTop()
    {
        gtlist.Items.Clear();

        string answer = await Consts.URL_GETTOP.PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { accountID = accountID, type = "relative", gjp = gjp }).ReceiveString();

        if (answer != "")
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex("|");

            if (reg.IsMatch(answer))
            {
                string[] users = answer.Split(new char[] { '|' });

                int i = 0;

                foreach (string user in users)
                {
                    string[] data = user.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                    Temp.topUsers[i] = data[1] + ":" + data[21];
                    i++;
                    if (data[1] != "")
                    {
                        gtlist.Items.Add((string)data[1]);
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                string[] data = answer.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                Temp.topUsers[0] = data[1] + ":" + data[21];
                if (data[1] != "")
                {
                    gtlist.Items.Add((string)data[1]);
                }
            }
        } else
        {
            Msg.ShowErrMessage("Ошибка", Consts.ERR);
        }
```

Исключение появляется на этой строке:

```
Temp.topUsers[i] = data[1] + ":" + data[21];
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Индекс выходит за границу массива. -- КО

Comment: @PavelMayorov однако, записывается всего 129

Comment: 129 чего записывается?

Comment: Научитесь пользоваться отладчиком. Посмотрите что находится в массивах `topUsers` и `data` когда происходит исключение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov кажись я понял, проблема в i++, т.к. i будет больше, чем возможно записать в массив

Comment: Вы вообще-то переменную `i` в этой строке не используете.

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатался

Answer (score 1):

Исключение исправлено так:

```
string answer = answ.Remove(answ.IndexOf('\t'), 3);

Regex reg = new Regex("|");

if (reg.IsMatch(answer))
{
    string[] users = answer.Split(new char[] { '|' });

    int i = 0;

    foreach (string user in users)
    {
        if (user == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        string[] data = user.Split(new char[] { ':' });
        Temp.topUsers[i] = data[1] + ":" + data[21];
        i++;
        if (data[1] != "")
        {
            gtlist.Items.Add((string)data[1]);
        }
    }
}
```